# JasperReports append % symbol

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am trying to display in xls 50 as 50.00%.
I tried following pattern "0.00%", however the result changes to 5000%.
I have tried patterns #%, \u0025 unicode but not getting the desired result.

I created a map which has column name and its corresponding pattern, formula (for custom formatting of columns in excel).
I was thinking of adding formula which would divide the values of the column by 100. 

and was providing this formula {$colmd.colValue}.divide(100), its unable read it either.

Problem is very similar to this http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/541903/how-add-percent-values-bar-chart

I am new to jasper/velocity, it would be great if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

In the IReport design: 
For y-axis Label text like 100.00%, 50.00% use Value AxisTick Label Mask as 0.00'%'

```
<valueAxisFormat>
    <axisFormat tickLabelMask="0.00'%'"/>
</valueAxisFormat>
```

For y-axis Label text like 100%, 50% use Value AxisTick Label Mask as #'%'

```
<valueAxisFormat>
    <axisFormat tickLabelMask="#'%'"/>
</valueAxisFormat>
```

graph example with current settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must use '%'. So pattern like this:
 0.00'%'

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/add-sign-after-value-axis-label

Comment: Its not working for me unfortunately. 5.5484 is getting displayed as 555'%' if I use #'%'. and '0.00'%'' is not working either.

Comment: Show output when pattern = 0.00'%' . Show part of jrxml with this pattern.
In my test report it's work perfectly. Which version of JR?

Comment: I am using 4.5.1 version for jasper-reports. We are creating jrxml file on the fly. We have a velocity template file, this file is read by velocity engine and converted to jrxml.

Comment: It is not interesting HOW you create jrxml. It is interesting WHAT in jrxml ("Show output when pattern = 0.00'%' . Show part of jrxml with this pattern."). You did not answer

Comment: <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.pattern" value="0.00'%'"/>

Comment: Remove this line (export parameter) and add pattern on field:      `<textField pattern="0.00&apos;%&apos;">
    <reportElement uuid="385f96ac-63c3-4802-a976-abda021e2c55" x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
    <textElement>
     <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FIRST}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>`

Comment: Invalid content was found starting with element '
textField'. One of '{"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":property, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":propertyExpre
ssion, "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":printWhenExpression}' is expected.

Comment: I have to use something like this  #if ($colmd.getPattern())
                    
                    <textField pattern="$colmd.getPattern()"> this is giving me error. Thanks for your help, appreciate it.Thats why we cannot ignore how we are generating/populating elements in jrxml file.

Answer (score 0):

On Jasper Studio 6.3.0:

**For show the value with a percent symbol on the top of each bar (in case of a bar chart):**

1. Right click on chart
2. Edit chart wizard
3. Add this for each serie: `CONCATENATE(TEXT($F{value},"#"),"%")`

XML:

```
<categorySeries>
    <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Serie1"]]></seriesExpression>
    <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></categoryExpression>
    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></valueExpression>
    <labelExpression><![CDATA[CONCATENATE(TEXT($F{value},"#"),"%")]]></labelExpression>
</categorySeries>
```

**For show the percent symbol in the Y axis follow this steps:**

1. Go to chart properties.
2. Find the Chart Plot tab.
3. Put this in the a property named "Value Axis Tick Label Mask": `#'%'`

XML:

```
<barPlot isShowLabels="true" isShowTickLabels="true" isShowTickMarks="true">
    <valueAxisFormat>
        <axisFormat labelColor="#0022FF" tickLabelMask="#'%'"></axisFormat>
    </valueAxisFormat>
</barPlot>
```